# How do I fix "http_client.c(227) Error creating a socket" error, which probably results from the OS

Tags: php, c, web-services, ubuntu, axis

I am in the process of setting up the wso2 php web services framework on my ubuntu 8.04 development server.

However my webservice is failing. Looking into the wsf_client.log (custom log for the framework) file gives me the error in the question.

I belive the error is returned from axis, but I have no idea how to fix it and would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: How do you make it impossible to click on your profile

Answer (score 2):

I'm only relaying information from the original questioner here, posted in a different forum:

> solved.
>
> thanks for the reply,
>
> I think my issue was a wrongly setup localhost in the apache conf,
>
> which caused the socket to try and connect in on itself.
>
> anyways a reinstall and change of localhost fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check /var/log/messages? If the error is at the OS level, you might have more clues in there.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can run your client with strace:

strace myprogram 2>&1 > myprogram.log

and examine log for system calls like socket().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not start the application as root but it is set to listen to a port number lower than 1024?